# Copying image in VBA

Tags: image, excel, vba

I have image ("picture") in ones of my worksheets ("mechanic"). How to copy this image to another worksheets ("character"), using VBA code? I try this:

```
Sub copy()
    workSheets("mechanic").Range("Picture").Select
    selection.copy
    workSheets("mechanic").Range("a8").paste
End Sub
```

Comment: Picture is not a `Range`, it's a `Shapes`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code:

```
Sub copy()
    Worksheets("mechanic").Shapes("Picture").Copy
    Worksheets("character").Range("A8").PasteSpecial
End Sub
```

Comment: How to adjust the picture to the size of cell?

Comment: after the code, `selection.width= range("A8").width` , and same for height.  aspectratio might get fuzzy...