# How to adjust the picture to the size of cell?

Tags: image, excel, vba

I copy the picture. How to adjust this picture to the size of cell, using VBA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code (Q related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23144196/copying-image-in-vba/23144267#23144267)):

```
Sub copy()
    Dim sh As Shape, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

    Set ws1 = Worksheets("mechanic")
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("character")

    ws1.Shapes("Picture").copy
    With ws2.Range("A8").MergeArea
        .PasteSpecial
        Set sh = ws2.Shapes(ws2.Shapes.Count) 'get last shape, i.e. pasted picture
        If .Height / sh.Height < .Width / sh.Width Then
            sh.ScaleHeight .Height / sh.Height, msoFalse
        Else
            sh.ScaleWidth .Width / sh.Width, msoFalse
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for help. It's works, but not when I merge cells. How to modify this code?