# How to keep shape from not moving and resizing new shape

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make a code to resize a shape to a defined size after inserting. I have successfully made it work but the problem is, whenever I insert a new one then run the code, the other shapes keep moving out from their initial location.

The shape I'm inserting is from a sign pad add-in, my output is shown

[image: here]

It supposed to be inside each cell and stay in it.

I have tried adding object position to the code "Don't move or size with cell" using the code : `.Placement = xlFreeFloating`; but still keeps moving.

My Code is:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub ResizePicture()
    Dim x As Integer
    For x = 1 To 35
    On Error GoTo endProc
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("SigPlus" & x).Height = 32.5984251969
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("SigPlus" & x).Width = 113.3858267717
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("SigPlus" & x).IncrementTop 4.5651968504
        On Error GoTo endProc
    Next x
    
endProc:
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Use `Placement = xlMove` - you want the image to move with the cell.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the your response, I have tried that also, but still the image/shape is still getting out of its place, it supposed to be inline or within the cell.

Comment: To place an image inside a cell, you need to use the Top, Left, Width and Height-properties of that cell, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23144507/how-to-adjust-the-picture-to-the-size-of-cell. However, you need to make up your mind about with/height ratio of the image (I guess you don't want it stretched), and you need to be aware that if a cell height is changed, the image will overlap into the next row.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestion FunThomas, I manage to make it work now based on that code, my code is:

```
Option Explicit

    Public Sub ResizePicture()
        Dim sh As Shape, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim Cel As Range
    Dim Rng As Range
        Set ws2 = Worksheets("Rev.0")
        Set Rng = Selection
    For Each Cel In Rng
        With Cel
            Set sh = ws2.Shapes(ws2.Shapes.Count) 'get last shape, i.e. pasted picture
            If .Height / sh.Height < .Width / sh.Width Then
                sh.ScaleHeight .Height / sh.Height, msoFalse
            Else
                sh.ScaleWidth .Width / sh.Width, msoFalse
            End If
        End With
        
        Next Cel
    End Sub
```