# Deleting the image in the marged cells

Tags: image, vba, excel

I want to delete different image (I copy image to this cell, using VBA code, so each image have another name), on merged cells (I don't want to unmarged cells). On this worksheet I have another images, so I can't use code like this:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.SelectAll
Selection.Delete
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code (Q related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23144196/copying-image-in-vba/23144267#23144267)):

```
Sub deletePicturesFromMergedCells()
    Dim sh As Shape, ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    Set ws = Worksheets("character")

    For Each sh In ws.Shapes
        'if shape is picture
        If sh.Type = msoPicture Or sh.Type = msoLinkedPicture Then
            'get entire range where picture placed
            Set rng = ws.Range(sh.TopLeftCell, sh.BottomRightCell)
            'if picture is in range A8 (with megred cells) then delete it
            If Not Intersect(rng, ws.Range("A8").MergeArea) Is Nothing Then
                sh.Delete
            End If
        End If
    Next sh
End Sub
```